# Customizing charts in high charts using data from csv

Tags: highcharts

I have loaded a csv file into a High Charts column chart: it works. However, I cannot figure out how to customize the chart. All the customizing options refer to hard-coded examples where the 'series' and 'categories' are right there in the code. Whereas mine is coming from a csv. How to use the customizing options? My x-axis is "Days" and y-axis is "Total Gallons"This is my code:

```
<script>
$.get('mergeHighChartsTotal.csv', function(csv) {
    $('#map2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'

        },
        data: {
            csv: csv

        },
            title: {
            text: 'Water Usage - September'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'gallons'
            }

        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a json dynamically, based on CSV. You need to load file and prepare custom parsing or use our data module. More infromation you can find here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing